# I am a Pakistani, in a same sex relationship, applying for a Tier 2 visa soon. What proof can my partner provide to apply for Tier 2 dependent?

Tags: united-kingdom, family

I have been living with my partner for more than a year now but we are in the closet so we don't have an address to our name or a joint bank statement. We have lots and lots of pictures but I don't think those would suffice in convincing the UKBA of the seriousness of our relationship. What else can my partner show as proof of relationship? Please help?

Comment: The country you're applying for is the UK? If so then https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/pbs-dependant-partner and https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/477216/PBS_dependant_guidance_11-15.pdf may be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

It may be difficult, if not impossible, to include your partner as a Tier 2 dependent, as you would need to prove that you've been living together in a relationship similar to marriage, and that it has been at least two years. Documentary evidence would include joint leases or rental agreements, bills for shared utility accounts, important documents for each of you that show the same address (identity cards, driver's license, passport).

That may limit your options. Your partner may be able to apply independently for his own long term UK visa. Another alternative could be for both of you to emigrate to another country which does recognize your union and, after the appropriate time, several years, apply to emigrate to the UK under the Tier 2 (or other) scheme.